# Paperclip not saving images on posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

Trying to learn rails etc by making a simple forum. I want users to be able to add an image to a post they create, but when I try it, it doesn't seem to add/save the picture. Paperclip is installed properly, as is ImageMagick. This is the code.

(btw I'm using .haml)

***Edit***: Changed .permit to (:image_file) so I can post now, but it doesn't attach the image.

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {large: "600x600>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100#"}
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**Form for posting**

```
= simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true }  do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content
  = f.file_field :image
  = f.submit
```

**Post Params**

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :image_file)
end
```

**Post Output**

```
#post_content
  %h1= @post.title
  %p= @post.content
  =image_tag @post.image.url(:medium)
```

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end


    def show
    end

    def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :image_file)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show your controller create action.

Comment: we nee controller action. and please check in public/ if something was created

Comment: have added in the post_controller now